# Installing node.js on Dreamhost VPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, dreamhost

I am trying to install node.js to Dreamhost VPS. I have followed the directions for Debian here https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager everything works great until I run

```
$checkinstall
```

Then it says

Failed to create temp dir!
** Do you have write permission for /var/tmp?

**** Aborting installation.

I cannot figure out how to change the directory based on the instructions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Updated**

When I contacted DH support they said "Our directory is not located at /var/tmp its > at /tmp so you just need to update your configuration to reflect the > correct path."

How to do what they suggested?...

Comment: have you tried using an SSH client to change the write permissions for the folder `/var/tmp`?

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. No I have not. I am new to SSH but catching on quickly can you share how to do that? When I contact support they said "Our directory is not located at /var/tmp its
> at /tmp so you just need to update your configuration to reflect the
> correct path."

Comment: Their support sounds awful. Just create the directory and set suitable permissions on it.

Comment: If you can (your ssh user have sudo permissions) from the shh prompt try this: Check is you already have a /var directory. if not then create it: "sudo mkdir /var". After that create a symbolic link: "sudo ln -s /tmp /var/tmp" . I would suggest this rather than to create the directory /var/tmp as the temporal directoy is periodicaly cleaned. If you manually create a /var/tmp i'm not pretty sure if this feature will already runing in this new directory. If you create a symbolic link to the right directory it might be safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for the `var/tmp` issue:

```
sudo mkdir /var/tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /var/tmp
```

**Updated

Here is how to install node.js to DreamHost:

```
tar -zxf node-v0.10.22.tar.gz
cd node-v0.10.22
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Viola!

Comment: Worked great until  "[User] is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/SSH

"Dreamhost does not allow sudo access on shared servers for security purposes, so the sudo command is not available. While many tasks can be accomplished without the use of sudo, if you do need sudo access, you may wish to check out DreamHost PS, where you get full root access!"